# почему не могу создать объект Canvas в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, canvas

[image: скрин среды юнити]

я пытаюсь создать объект Canvas в свою игру, но не могу его найти. Максимум, что я могу это добавить компонент Canvas в инспекторе камеры. Но добавить кнопок или что-то типо того - не могу.

Answer (score 0):

ладно, извиняюсь, что потревожил. Я просто установил пакет связанный с UI, теперь всё работает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]